# Log4j2 Configuration at class level or package level

Tags: logging, log4j2

Is it necessary to specify the logger at the package level in log4j2.xml or can I specify the logger at the class level as well ?

I am trying to use this below config where MyApp is a class under the package com.foo.Bar. The first configuration doesn't seem to work but the second one does.

```
# Doesn't work 
<Logger name="com.foo.Bar.MyApp" level="trace" additivity="false">
     <AppenderRef ref="stdout" level="all"/>
</Logger>

# Works
<Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace" additivity="false">
     <AppenderRef ref="stdout" level="all"/>
</Logger>
```

NOTE : MyApp is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

The logger was defined by the name of the child class and thats why it wasn't getting printed when I used "com.foo.Bar.MyApp".

Once I started using it with the name of the child class it worked.